# Regular Expression \n (new line) error

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text-box with regular expression. My issue is that as soon as I exit the text-box (after entering content in it),

I get a

> "Contains illegal characters"  error

I deducted that this only happens after I click on the ENTER key. What's weird is that if there is no content in the text-box and I press on ENTER, I don't get an error. The error appears only when I've entered content and then pressed ENTER. (I hope I explained myself correctly...)

Here's the regular expression I have: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_א-ת?!:'\"%$;@. ,()-/\r\n*]*$"`

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that's all UTF-8? I'm not sure how nice right-to-left text is when used in a regular expression set. Where are you getting this error? If that's just a string, what context is it used in?

Comment: Why do you have white space? **`. ,`** why not use `\s`?

Comment: What text entered causes the error? How are you invoking the regular expression?

Comment: If you are specifying the regexp as a string, then creating the regexp using `new RegExp`, then you need to escape backslashes with an extra backslash in order to get them into the regexp, as in `\\r`. Otherwise you will end up with a physical newline in your regexp, which will not work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have a minor mistake in your regex

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_א-ת?!:'\"%$;@. ,()-/\r/\n*]*$"
```

You missed a forward slash before \n

Comment: Why do I need a forward slash before `\n`? What would be the effect of omitting it?